# Add attribute or node content to page DOM

Tags: xml, dom

I have set of xml elements like this:

```
<item code="<HTML_CODE>" />
```

For example:

```
<items>
    <item code='<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>' />
    <item code='<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>' />
</items>
```

All special characters in code attribute are escaped (< - <, > - &rt;, etc)
Is there any way to append content of code attributes to page DOM and  render it, as html? 
I mean, in case of my examples, after all, I need two hyperlinks on the page.

UPDATE

I have:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
<materials>
<items>
<item project_id="3" code="&lt;a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot;&gt;Text&lt;/a&gt;" txt_id="text1" text="&#171;&#1050;&#1086;&#1088;&#1086;&#1083;&#1077;&#1074;&
#1089;&#1090;&#1074;&#1086;&#187; &#8212; &#1073;&#1088;&#1072;&#1091;&#1079;&#1077;&#1088;&#1085;&#1072;&#1103; &#1088;&#1086;&#1083;&#1077;&#1074;&#1072;&#1103; &#1086;&#1085;&#1083;&#1072;&#1081;&#1085;-&#1080;&#1075;&#1088;&#1072;" />
<item project_id="3" code="Texttextetx" />
</items>
</materials>
</root>
```

I need:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
...anything here..
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://google.com">Text</a>
Texttextetx <!-- I know, this is bad but this is example-->
</body>
```

Comment: This is not well-formed XML, Please, edit the question and show a complete (as small as possible) source XML document and the complete (x)HTML you want as result, plus any rules that the transformation must implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="XPATHQUERY" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it. in JQuery

```
$('item').each(function(){
     $("#receiving_div").append($(this).attr('code'));
})
```

However, wouldn't it make more sense to just return the HTML rather than wrap HTML in XML? They're both just markup languages anyway...

Comment: Xml won't go to the browser, it transform on server-side by python lib lxml.etree.

Answer (score 0):

```
<item project_id="3" code="&lt;a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot;&gt;Text&lt;/a&gt;" txt_id="text1" text="&#171;&#1050;&#1086;&#1088;&#1086;&#1083;&#1077;&#1074;& 
#1089;&#1090;&#1074;&#1086;&#187; &#8212; &#1073;&#1088;&#1072;&#1091;&#1079;&#1077;&#1088;&#1085;&#1072;&#1103; &#1088;&#1086;&#1083;&#1077;&#1074;&#1072;&#1103; &#1086;&#1085;&#1083;&#1072;&#1081;&#1085;-&#1080;&#1075;&#1088;&#1072;" /> 
<item project_id="3" code="Texttextetx" />
```

The value of an attribute by definition cannot be nodes -- it is just a string. Thus, the `href` attribute above doesn't contain any markup at all -- it contains destroyed markup.

Such a string cannot be used immediately by XSLT/XPath -- it must first be parsed by an XML parser.

So, if you need to process this with XSLT, the xslt code has to use an extension function that will parse the value of the `href` attribute and will return a node-set.

As we see again and again, it is stupid and harmful to try to put markup in an attribute -- this only destroys it.

Comment: I don't mean to save node on attribute. I mean, is there anything like function eval("string with code"), from smthing like python, js or php?

Comment: I'd be surprized if there is -- escaping markup is a recognized bad practice. So, you'll need two steps: first unescape the content of the attrbute (there must be function named something like `html-unencode()`. Then `xml-parse()` this string, finally apply the full XML- API that you have on the node(s) parsed from the unescaped string.